# How to validate UITextField.text in a custom Cell not greater then by above custom UITextFiled.text in a UITableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITextFiled in CustomCell. Then I am loading these Cell in UITableView of ProductDelivery Class. I am assigning some Initial Value to UITextField *txtQty CellForRowAtIndexPath Method.

My problem is that I want to validate the values entered by the User in UITextField not must be greater then by Above Cell UItextField.

When User Enter the value in UITextField CustomCell Class DidEndEding method class But I want to have this value in UITableView Class That is Product Delivery. So I can validate it and reload the UITableView with new Value. Could anyone assist me to solve this problem please??

```
@interface ProductDeliveryCell : UITableViewCell<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextField *txtQty;
@end

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProDeliveryCell";
    cell =(ProductDeliveryCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) 
{

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductDeliveryCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0]; 
    }
 cell.txtQty.text=del.Qty;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Plz believe me , how Can I accept an answer that is not correct or not providing correct solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to store all entered values in a special dictionary.
You should create `NSMutableDictionary` where you'll put your values. And every `UITextField` in your cells should have it's own tag set to `indexPath.row` value (in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` message). Now in the `textField:didEndEditing` message you should store the value entered with code like this:

```
[valuesDictionary setValue:textField.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"field%02d", textField.tag]];
```

So you could check any entered value whenever you want. Just get edited textfield's tag and pick the value of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"field%02d", tag-1]` key from the dictionary.

Comment: Why not just use the indexPath as the key?

Comment: but When I touch or tap UITextField it calls only CustomCell DidEndEditing delegate Method.

Comment: Just assign the delegate of UITextField to the ViewController of UITableView.

Comment: Mundi, how (and why) you want to use indexPath as a key of a dictionary? The key is much better when it's just NSString. You can easily NSLog the whole dictionary for full information of it's content.

Comment: Pandey, if you don't want to set UIViewController as a delegate for text fields, you could create your own protocol for cells and ask cell's delegate for a reference value. But you'll still need to implement this delegate message in your UIViewController. There's no other way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Now save textField value when entered in a variable say currentValue;

use UITextFieldDelegates in this matter.Check whether entered value is greater than above entered value

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(currentValue > 0)//(!(currentValue == 0)) //intially it will be zero
    {
       if([textField.text intValue] > currentValue)
       {
             //message value greater
             textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length] - 1]; //remove last number entered
        }
     }
}
```

save new Value

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  currentValue = [textField.text intValue]; //save new Value
}
```

Comment: When UITextFiled tap how Do I know which cells it belongs bcoz it call only CustomCell Delegate methods

Comment: add tag to each and every UITextField so that u can know which cell's textField is this by [textField tag]

Comment: Price, Actually I want reference of UITextField in the ProductDelivery Class in which I have UItableview. Its calling only CustomCell class UITextField Delegate methods

Comment: Thank you , In my Tableview(Product Delivery) Class I declare uitextfielddelegate protocol. then in cellForRowAtIndexPath I assign self to my UITextField Delegate then Overide Above delegate methods now its working. cell.txtQty.delegate=self;